# How can I set <aside> element to the right of page?

Tags: html, css

How can I put `<aside>` to the right, next to `<body>` ? 
I tried `<aside align=right>` and `aside{ align-self: right}` in CSS and it doesn`t work.

Comment: right next to `body`....what is that mean...?

Comment: You shouldn't have anything "next to body".  `<body>` should _contain_ the rest of your markup.

Comment: Does this help you? https://jsfiddle.net/1fwkkxL9/1/

Comment: Like in ads menu, next to "main" text of page.

Comment: How you "put something on the right" is very context sensitive.

Comment: @Quentin I putted links below.

Comment: Don't do that. Put a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I`ll post image links in next questions. However, any tips ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  **IMAGES of, or remote links to, code are not acceptable.**

Comment: @Paulie_D Understood, thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header, main, aside, footer {
   padding: 6px;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: #d10373;
  color: #fff;
  }

main {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
   width: 80%;
}

aside {
   width: 19%;
   background-color: #ffccff;
   }
   
footer {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<body>
   <header>Your header goes here</header>
   <main>
       <article>
   Your article goes here
       </article>
       <aside>
            <ul>
              <li>This</li>
              <li>is</li>
              <li>your</li>
              <li>aside</li>
            </ul>
       </aside>
   </main>
   <footer>
   Here's a footer
   </footer>
</body>
```

Note that the `<aside>` goes inside the `<body>` and that the container for the content is called `<main>`.

You can [learn how to use HTML5 semantic elements here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).

And here's a [guide to using `flex-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp).

(edited to remove unnecessary adjustments for Safari)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: also note that if you use the height (80vh) it won't work in Safari, so you need to put 80% as well; and if the content overflows, it's a good idea to set it to `overflow: auto`, which will add a scrollbar if necessary.

Comment: would the people downvoting this like to explain why they are downvoting it?

Comment: I have now changed the layout to `flex-wrap` instead of `inline-block` which was probably why people were downvoting my answer, @AlexT.

Comment: So 100 it s default browser s height except Safari ?  Can`t I use px instead of vh ?

Comment: vh = viewport height, so it is responsive to lots of different devices (but Safari ignores vh); px is a fixed height (not a good idea when you want to make it work on lots of different size screens); % doesn't work for height. Probably don't need to worry about height now I have changed it to `flex-wrap`

Comment: yep, just edited my answer to remove `height` property on `article` and `aside`

Comment: article here about different CSS units and when to use them https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: @YvonneAburrow The issues with vh support on iOS7 have been resolved since 2014, and Safari on the desktop has supported vh since v.6.1.  There has been virtually universal support for viewport units for several years, and it's quite safe to use: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: _"it won't work in Safari,"_  this is just nonsense.

Comment: thanks @jme11 that's good to know.